# 554 5.7.1 <user@domain.com>: Relay access denied

Tags: postfix

I've looked at the postings for this similar issue and tried the suggestions with no luck.

Please help me figure out why no emails can be received by my postfix server.

I have my MX record pointing to my postfix server

Here is my main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = cumail.circircuitsunited.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 localhost
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
allow_percent_hack = no
```

Comment: Have you looked at the logs of your mail server?

Comment: One thing that stands out is `myhostname = cumail.circircuitsunited.com`. I can't resolve `circircuitsunited.com`. I can however resolve `circuitsunited.com`. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 3):

Your `myhostname` looks like a typo, I assume `circircuitsunited.com` should rather be `circuitsunited.com`.

```
$ nslookup -type=mx circuitsunited.com
Non-authoritative answer:
circuitsunited.com      mail exchanger = 50 ec2-52-52-52-169.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
$ telnet ec2-52-52-52-169.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 25
Trying 52.52.52.169...
Connected to ec2-52-52-52-169.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220-cumail.circircuitsunited.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
```

This confirms that is your server. You have a typo in your `myhostname` directive. The variable `$mydomain` [defaults to $myhostname minus the first component](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydomain), so your server currently only accepts mails for `circircuitsunited.com`.

On a side note: You should set the same DNS records (forward and reverse) that you are using for this machine. Invalid hostnames are often used for spam detection. A hostname that doesn't match will increase your spam likelihood.